# How can I add an if statement in a stripos?

Tags: php

how can I keep the **p=** and add an OR **/20** on it ? I mean I want to check both strings.

```
<?php if ( false==stripos(get_permalink($post->ID), 'p=') ) { ?>
```

Comment: BTW use the === operator to check for false value cause str(i)pos can also return 0

Comment: Better yet, just avoid `stripos` altogether. PHP has a lovely function called [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr) which does not necessitate boolean equality probing.

Comment: @mario: I thought strpos is faster and uses less memory

Comment: @PeeHaa: It does. But the factual difference won't make a blip in your profiler. The readability advantage otoh is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test for two portions of strings with a single `stripos()` call : you have to call `stripos()` twice.

Depending on what you exactly want to achieve *(not sure I really undertand the question)*, you'll combine those two with `&&` or `||` :

```
$link = get_permalink($post->ID);
if (stripos($link, 'p=')!==false && stripos($link, '/20')!==false) {
    // the link contains both p= AND /20
}
```

or :

```
$link = get_permalink($post->ID);
if (stripos($link, 'p=')!==false || stripos($link, '/20')!==false) {
    // the link contains p= OR (inclusive) /20
}
```

As a sidenote : you should use `===` or `!==`, as `stripos()` can return `0` or `false` -- and those don't have the same meaning.

Comment: you mean like `if ( false==stripos(get_permalink($post->ID), 'p=') ) || if ( false==stripos(get_permalink($post->ID), '/20') )` ?

Comment: @Punkis no, I mean combining the two stripos() call in a single condition -- I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: I don't know I can't get it working.. It was working when I only had the p= though

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it twice:

```
if(  false===stripos(get_permalink($post->ID), 'p=') || 
   false===stripos(get_permalink($post->ID), '/20')
) {
```